# Как включить консоль на heroku?

Tags: python, консоль, бот, heroku

Бонжур)
Можно ли включить консоль в `heroku`? Если да то как?

Answer (score 0):

1. heroku run bash
2. В браузере открыть dashboard.heroku.com, выбрать приложение и в выпадающем списке More выбрать Run console